# Why local notifications are not immediately shown when created with phonegap?

Tags: android, plugins, cordova, notifications

I use the Phonegap LocalNotification plugin to implement local notifications.

The code is shown below.

```
var d=new Date();
var tid=Math.floor(Math.random()*100000)+1);
plugins.localNotification.add({
  date: d,
  message: "New Message\r\nContent",
  ticker: "Sample Ticker",
  repeatDaily: false,
  id: tid
});
```

The strange thing is that it will fire off, but some time later after the notification is added (a couple of minutes later). What are the possible reasons for this?

I am using Cordova 2.9.0, on Android platform.

Answer (score 0):

One reason could be that the deviceReady event was not fired.

Second reason could be that the localNotification plugin  runs only on cordova 3.x.x

Comment: The log shows "onetime notification added ..." when app is lauched and deviceReady is fired. The notification shows anyway, just being delayed.